# Dagger hilt Cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, android-mvvm

I am new with dagger using. So, I can't solve whats the problem with this. I just want to ask here to solve it.

This is the error:

> C:\Users\msi\Documents\MyAndroidProjects\MovieProjects\app\build\generated\hilt\component_sources\debug\com\example\movieapp\App_HiltComponents.java:128:
> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding]
> com.example.movieapp.api.MovieAppService cannot be provided without an
> @Provides-annotated method.   public abstract static class SingletonC
> implements App_GeneratedInjector,
> ^
> com.example.movieapp.api.MovieAppService is injected at
> com.example.movieapp.repository.MovieRepository(movieAppService)
> com.example.movieapp.repository.MovieRepository is injected at
> com.example.movieapp.viewmodel.MainViewModel(repository, �)
> com.example.movieapp.viewmodel.MainViewModel is injected at
> com.example.movieapp.viewmodel.MainViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
> @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>
> is requested at
> dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap()
> [com.example.movieapp.App_HiltComponents.SingletonC ?
> com.example.movieapp.App_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ?
> com.example.movieapp.App_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]

MainViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel@Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MovieRepository,
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
) : ViewModel() {

    val movieList = MutableLiveData<Resource<Movie>>()

    fun getAllMovies(movieName: String) {
        movieList.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                if (hasInternetConnection(context)) {
                    val response = repository.getMovies(movieName, "ffe9063f")
                    movieList.postValue(Resource.Success(response.body()!!))
                } else
                    movieList.postValue(Resource.Error("Internet yok"))
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                when (ex) {
                    is IOException -> movieList.postValue(Resource.Error("Network Failure " + ex.localizedMessage))
                    else -> movieList.postValue(Resource.Error("Conversion Error"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MovieRepository.kt

```
@Singleton
class MovieRepository @Inject constructor(private val movieAppService: MovieAppService) {

    suspend fun getMovies(title: String, aKey: String): Response<Movie> = withContext(
        Dispatchers.IO
    ) {
        val movies = movieAppService.getMovies(title = title, aKey = aKey)
        movies
    }
}
```

ApiModule.kt

```
class ApiModule {
    @Module
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    object ApiModule {

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
            return HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideOkHttpClient(logging: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
            return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // connect timeout
                .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build()
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideMovieAppService(retrofit: Retrofit): MovieAppService {
            return retrofit.create(MovieAppService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

MovieAppService.kt

```
interface MovieAppService {

    companion object {
        const val ENDPOINT = "http://www.omdbapi.com/"
    }

    @GET(".")
    suspend fun getMovies(@Query("t") title: String,@Query("apikey") aKey: String): Response<Movie>
}
```

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Yunus Dilber's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not wrap your singleton object module with a **same named** class. Change your module file like this or change your class name

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ApiModule {
    
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        return HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(logging: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // connect timeout
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMovieAppService(retrofit: Retrofit): MovieAppService {
        return retrofit.create(MovieAppService::class.java)
    }
    
}
```